# debug C for UNIX API on Windows 7 with Cygwin?

Tags: c, unix, cygwin

I am just learning about Cygwin, and it appears to make possible to write C code against the UNIX API, and then have it run on Windows, provided you build it in the Cygwin environment.

I have gotten accustomed to the Visual Studio IDE and debugging tools, so wanted to ask: is it somehow possible to write and build C in Windows, and then debug it with Visual Studio, with the help of Cygwin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually possible to debug UNIX apps with Visual Studio. See [Utilities and SDK for Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732759).

Answer (score 2):

No, because the VS debugging tools (for the most part) depend heavily on it being compiled using the MS C compiler, rather than GCC.

So if you manage to bootload it in, you won't get any of the more useful debugging features VS offers.

The closest alternative to Visual Studio that supports GCC is [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org).

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio isn't an option for your case because the VS collection of tools are designed to work with code compiled using the VS C compiler and not GCC. In lieu of Visual Studio, I suggest [Codelite](http://www.codelite.org/). It's designed specifically as a cross-platform IDE that will be familiar to developers that have migrated from Visual Studio. It will of course handle GCC or Clang.

In comparison to CodeBlocks (another potential IDE you can use), Codelite has a large number of features that are slightly improved, but it does have a few that are worth mentioning individually.

- Clang driven code-completion and code tagging. This is separate from the compiler, so even when compiling with GCC the IDE can provide you with Clang-based features. As a word of caution, Clang supported features are not yet entirely implemented. For instance, Clang code suggestions aren't present, and code-completion doesn't yet work for Objective-C.
- Partial support for Objective-C out of the box. CodeBlocks needs to be properly setup to correctly handle Objective-C projects, while Codelite can handle them without any modifications. I say partial support for Objective-C because of the aforementioned missing code-completion for Objective-C methods and classes.
- Much higher quality build error output window; catalogues all build errors and warnings by message, file and project. The only thing I can directly compare it to is the build error output window in Xcode.

My suggestion is to try both IDEs and decide on which will better suit your needs.

Comment: That's an interesting IDE, haven't seen it before. Personally for C++ I use CodeBlocks and for C# I use Visual Studio, but I'm certain there are a variety of alternatives. Any particular standout features of Codelite when compared with CodeBlocks?

Comment: @AT, I've edited and expanded my answer to hopefully answer your question (I couldn't fit it in this comment). It certainly isn't an exhaustive answer as there are numerous improvements over CodeBlocks (which is the IDE I myself migrated from to Codelite). Eran Ifrah is the creator of Codelite and he's usually very receptive of any questions or comments people have about it. You can find him on the Codelite forums or here on SO.

Comment: Thanks for adding that in. Just setup Codelite, and have a few critiques when compared with CodeBlocks: • Codelite's code-formatter doesn't work properly (clicked attach braces and a few other settings; but it didn't attach them) • I couldn't get my C++ to compile, even after modifying the binary directories accordingly (seems to lack the `"dir name"` for spaces) • No preparsing compiler, underlining mistakes (e.g.: forgotten semicolon... not sure if CodeBlocks has this ATM)